# How do I do multiple replaces on a string at the same time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, replace

```
string rawConnString = Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString;
```

I want to do this with "rawConnString":

```
rawConnString.Replace("<<DATA_SOURCE>>", server);
rawConnString.Replace("<<INITIAL_CATALOG>>", "tempdb");
```

Then set the final string to variable finalConnString.

How would I go about doing this?

This is ASP .NET 4.0/C# btw.

Comment: One of [DbConnectionStringBuilder's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) implementations may yield better code.

Comment: @AustinSalonen - Yes, it would!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string finalString = Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString.Replace("<<DATA_SOURCE>>", server).Replace("<<INITIAL_CATALOG>>", "tempdb");
```

will do it all in one line of code.  But it's uglier IMO because you'll have to scroll.  The code in your question seems a ***LOT*** cleaner and more readable to me.

And doing it in one line of code won't help your performance at all.  It should all compile down to the same MSIL either way.  I'd leave it as you had it.

Comment: I have to assume he is looking for a solution which would only require one pass through the string.  I removed the downvote though because the question is unclear.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for. i wasnt aware i could chain replaces. thanks! ps. can only accept in 10 mins.

Comment: @EdS. You could be right.  If so, I'll delete this so as not to leave an invalid answer out there.  If there IS a way to do it in one pass, I'll definitely vote that person up.  I don't think there is.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but you can chain them:

```
var finalConnString = rawConnString.Replace("<<DATA_SOURCE>>", server)
    .Replace("<<INITIAL_CATALOG>>", "tempdb");
```

If you're looking to do it with a single method call, I don't think there's anything native to .NET.  You can always create an extension method though.  Here's a [performance-conscious `ReplaceMany` implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/310525/The-ReplaceMany-Method) (signature `.ReplaceMany(string[] oldValues, string[] newValues)`).

Answer (score 1):

you mean something like this

```
string tempString=rawConnString.Replace("<<DATA_SOURCE>>", server);
sting finalstring=tempString.Replace("<<INITIAL_CATALOG>>", "tempdb");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is frankly trivial; you have 90% of the code you need:

```
string rawConnString = Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString;

string finalConnString = rawConnString
                            .Replace("<<DATA_SOURCE>>", server)
                            .Replace("<<INITIAL_CATALOG>>", "tempdb");
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid using two back-to-back calls of `Replace`, you can use regular expressions. However, this is far less readable than the original:

```
string connString = Regex.Replace(
    rawConnString
,   "(<<DATA_SOURCE>>)|(<<INITIAL_CATALOG>>)"
,   m => m.Groups[1].Success ? server : "tempdb"
);
```

[Link to ideone.](http://ideone.com/jMf1I)

Answer (score 0):

First, String.replace does not change the original string: it creates a new string. So you have to assign the return value to something. So the logically simplest thing to do is:

```
finalstring=rawConnString.Replace("<<DATA_SOURCE>>", server);  
finalstring=finalstring.Replace("<<INITIAL_CATALOG>>", "tempdb");
```

Note that for the second replace, you want to start with the results of the first replace, not the original string.

As String.replace returns a string, and String.replace takes a string, you might find it easier to run them together:

```
finalstring=rawConnString.Replace("<<DATA_SOURCE>>", server).Replace("<<INITIAL_CATALOG>>", "tempdb");
```